# Checking connection between two computers connected to the same wi-fi

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, lan, connection

I need to check if two PCs (windows 10 and 7) connected to the same wi-fi are able to communicate between them. Some days ago I know that they communated because I used "Spacedesk" and "Mouse without borders", but now these do not work anymore so I suspect that there is a communication problem. How can I check it?

---

EDIT:

IP win7: 192.168.1.141

IP win10: 192.168.1.171

I tried to run `ping 192.168.1.141` in the terminal of the windows 10, but I get the message "destination host unreachable".

If I do the same on the other PC `ping 192.168.1.171` I get the message "request time out".

---

EDIT 2: if I connect both PCs to my smartphone's hotspot, the above two softwares work, so it's a problem related to the wi-fi of the router.

---

EDIT 3: I changed the local IP addresses of both PCs, and the problem persists when I use the router network.

Comment: First test: check the IP addresses of both machines, then try `ping <Win.7.IP.address>` from Win 10 machine, or vice versa. If that fails, check if the router/AP allows connectivity between the Wi-Fi clients - that might be disallowed due to security.

Comment: Hello @Peregrino69 I tried the command ping Win.7.IP.192.168.1.141 (this is the local IP of the windows 7 PC) on the windows 10 PC, but it says impossible to find the host, check if the name is correct

Comment: @Peregrino69 where should I check if the router/AP allows connectivity between the Wi-Fi clients?

Comment: Try just `ping 192.168.1.141` - my bad :-) Please don't add tests and results in comments, edit your question to add new info instead. That way it's readily available for all community members who want to pitch in.

Comment: It's a setting on the AP / router, so somewhere in the mgmt interface. Did you try pinging the IP address?

Comment: If it worked some days ago, and you haven't changed router/ap settings after that, then don't touch router/ap settings. They won't change by themselves, so the settings should still be just as good as they were some days ago.

Comment: Hello @svin83 I didn't change anything, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Peregrino69 see the edit please, I tried to ping the IP address of the other PC

Comment: If you pinged the IP addresses, please edit the commands in the question. The commands you now show there will not succeed. There's no need to hide IPs starting with 192.168 - those can only be used in internal networks, so there's no way at all to access them without knowing the external public IP address.

Comment: @Peregrino69 instead of writing numbers I wrote local... for the sake of brevity

Comment: Clarity and details are much more important than brevity, my friend :-)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct IP addresses? I'm guessing your LAN (and thus WiFi) is set up with DHCP to automatically assign IP addresses for each device just like most networks? DHCP assigned IPs will usually change at one time or another... Try the command `ipconfig` to show current IP.

Comment: Hi @svin83 I took the IP addreses from ipconfig command (on both PCs); they concide with the IP addresses I found in the router settings...the DHCP setting is on as usual.

Comment: Look for an option named client separation in your router. This must be disabled. If the router has VLANs configured then both computers must (usually) be on the same VLAN. Did you set the wifi network as "public" in Windows Networking on one or both computers? Try changing it to "home" or "work" if you did...